# Variação da pronúncia do treze

Tags: pronúncia, regionalismo, números

Algumas pessoas em Portugal tendem a dizer o numeral treze como "treuze"?

Qual é a origem desta pronúncia? Porque ela tornou-se popular?

Comment: Interessante que eu não encontrei, por mais que tenho uma pesquisa rápida, muito desse modo de falar, *treuze*, mesmo nos sites que "explicavam" o sotaque lisboeta.

Comment: Isso é regional. Como intérprete já ouvi muito isso e me parece que foram falantes dos **Azores (São Miguel)**. Mas é possível que seja outro lugar. Me dei conta rapidamente que a pessoa estava dizendo treze. Existem também outras palavras nas quais o U foi transformado en EU mas já não me lembro.

Comment: Eu já ouvi "douze" no Porto.

Comment: Particularmente achei genial a variação de pronuncia da palavra “treze” e “doze”. Muitas vezes é imperceptível a diferença de alguém que está dizendo “três anos” e “treze anos”. O “Treuze”, pelo menos, não gera essa dúvida. 

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com [CiberDúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/treze/779), *treuze* é um regionalismo de Lisboa.

Comment: No Alentejo também se utiliza. Se surgiu em Lisboa, gostaria de conhecer mais sobre a origem. Caso conheça alguma fonte de estudo, pode indicá-la por favor?

Comment: @felipe.zkn, [este site](https://portuguesaletra.com/duvidas/treze-ou-treuze/) diz que surgiu em Lisboa, mas não incluí por eu não conhecer bem a fonte. Para mim, brasileiro com sotaque originário caipira e bem ajuntado, falar *treuze* é mais fácil do que *treze* **se** eu estiver falando fraco, o que faria mais sentido no português de Portugal por ser mais átono. Imagino que venha disso.

Comment: Eu diria também que foram pessoas do campo que eu ouvi fazer essa mudança. Não Lisboetas. Talvez tenha a ver com nível de estudos. Eu não sei.

Answer (score 1):

É impossível dizer ao certo por que razão se tornou popular, mas uma possibilidade é o facto de a pronúncia de *treze* ser muito próxima da de *três* quando a palavra seguinte começa com uma vogal. Geralmente é possível adicionar uma semivogal /j/ como em *treze anos* `[tɾezjɐnuʃ]`, mas por exemplo *treze e meio* e *três e meio* pronunciam-se exactamente da mesma maneira.